# What is this bush in my yard with many small green apples?

Tags: identification, shrubs

[Here](https://davesgarden.com/community/forums/fp.php?pid=8443993#b) is a picture of a bush in my yard. It is now late June and little quarter size green apples are all over it.  Can you tell me what type of bush this is?

Comment: Welcome to the site Helen! The picture link you provided had some problems. I corrected them so people can see your picture. Also, we don't print email addresses, in order to protect your privacy! We post our answers here so you can come back and read them, and because it gives our whole community the chance to learn from your question, which we already have through the answer you received! Please read our [help] pages for a complete explanation of our system, as it's different from others. It's lovely to meet you and we hope to see you around!

Answer (score 4):

That's a [flowering quince, a chaenomeles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaenomeles), sometimes also called Japanese quince. With just one picture (apparently not even from your plant?) and various hybrids on the market I couldn't say *exactly* which variety, but the little apples will turn yellow in fall and are edible.

Comment: Quince jelly: https://www.google.com/search?q=quince+jelly&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: Great plant...be nice to see but probably 99.9 % Stephie is correct.  There are 2 varieties, both are beautiful, useful and provide edibles.  If your shrub is near walkways or places to sit, not so much.  Please send pics to include the environment...